# Using Google Chrome Dev tools on Android (emulator)

Tags: android, css, google-chrome-devtools, emulation, read-eval-print-loop

I need to debug CSS for some site running on the device under Android (in the common REPL mode). As I know it is possible to connect the device with the desktop via USB cable to do that. But the problem is I have no such a device (with Android). I have the Android emulator (Andy) but it seems that chrome installed on it has no dev tools at all. 
So is it possible to solve the problem without physical Android device?

UPD==================

Once again:
The point is **I have no any Android device**. I have an emulator for it only (Andy Android emulator).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android AVD Emulator Dev Tools for Mobile Browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658044/android-avd-emulator-dev-tools-for-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 98):

Navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices` on your chrome browser.

From there, you should see a list of attached devices (including emulators, not sure about Andy), but if it is possible, that's where you would find it.

Comment: then what?  you can't click on the device

Comment: I can see the list of devices, but you are not answering the question. How can inspect the emulator from Chrome?

Comment: Sorry folks, this answer was 5 years old at the time you commented, and Chrome has changed just a _tad_ in that interim. There are options both in the sidebar to choose pages on the device or you can configure remote targets for the device and then use the options therein to inspect the page loaded on the device.

Comment: In the device list, there should be a "inspect" button to open the web developer tool for that device.

Answer (score 42):

Adding to Josh's answer, I've had to:

1. Navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices` on my machine.
2. Open Chrome in Andy.
3. List devices with `adb devices`.

Andy finally shows up in Chrome's devices list.

Comment: adb devices is what helped me as well! Thanks!

Comment: running `adb devices` resolved my issues as well since it ensures the daemon is running and attaches any running devices

Answer (score 18):

In this context, "phone" is your emulator.

First you must enable debugging on your phone:

Settings > About Phone > Build number > Tap it 7 times to become developer;

then:

Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging.

Then navigate to **chrome://inspect/#devices**. You should find the open tab on your phone there.

Comment: It works without enabling USB Debugging now! Thanks for the update. :)